# Ubuntu 15.10 Can't change output source from HDMI to wireless Blutooth Headset

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth, alsa, hdmi

I have researched similar problems, and have not had any success.

I've connected my Sony headsets over Blutooth. "HDMI" and "Headset" are both listed as outputs in the GUI sound settings. It seems HDMI is locked as the default, and clicking on "Headset" does open the option to change settings for Headset, neither can profiles be deleted. Note: My motherboard does not have Blutooth capabilities, so a Blutooth-USB is used.

[Sound Settings Locked on HDMI / DisplayPort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OWgx.png)

Other solutions imply using the Terminal. I've listed the card profiles using

```
pacmd list-cards
```

index 0 is "HDA ATI HDMI", alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
index 1 is "HDA ATI SB", alsa_card_pci-0000_00_14.2
index 2 is the headset, bluez_card.[MAC address]

I then tried to set the index 2 card profile to 0.

```
pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:bluez_card.[MAC Address]
```

or (using the alias of the device)

```
pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:MDR-ZX330BT
```

etc. All commands generated "No such profile"

Next, I tried to set the default output:

```
pacmd set-defualt-source bluez_card.[MAC address]
```

again, "No Such Profile". Pressing tab after "set-default source" automatically gives three options, none of which are "bluez"

alsa_input_pci........analog-stereo
alsa_input_pci........analog-stereo.monitor
alsa_input_pci........hdmi-stereo.monitor

I know this is quite a mess, but any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have no real answer, but I have made good expiriance to use pulseaudio.
If you want you can give it a try with

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Hope that helps you.

Regards,
   Kai

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, Pulse Audio is already installed (by default). The command "pacmd" is pulse audio.

I think the error might have something to do with the blutooth adapter, or perhaps missing drivers for headphones.

Comment: Oh I was not aware of that, as I', just used the frontend :-/ As you just post a image of the standard sound settings. On my Ubuntu Unity 15.10 pacmd worsk also without puleaudio installed. Mybe you can give the pulseaudio frontend a chance :-)